# need to plot graph from internal storage file

Tags: android

I am storing my data which is coming from hardware device (i.e console), 1st i am creating the file in my device as follows -->>

```
 final String folderName = LOGGING_ROOT_FOLDER;

    File folder = new File(folderName);

    if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
        boolean ret = folder.mkdirs();
        if (ret != true) {
            return null; // return empty string if fail.
        }
    }

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS", Locale.US);
    final String fileName = folderName + File.separator + firstName + "-" + patientId + "-" + procedureId + "-"
            + sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ".log";

    File f = new File(fileName);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        customLogFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After creating the file i am storing the data in my device as .log with flag (below i have given the code )-->>

```
if (customLogFile != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);
            final String d = mFormatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            if (pdMeanValue != -1) {
                sb.append(pdMeanValue);
            }
            sb.append("|");

            if (aoMean != -1) {
                sb.append(aoMean);
            }
            sb.append("|");

            if (aoMap != -1) {
                sb.append(aoMap);
            }
            sb.append("|");

            if (ffrValue != -1) {
                sb.append(ffrValue);
            }
            sb.append("|");

            if (ffrLowestValue != -1) {
                sb.append(ffrLowestValue);
            }
            sb.append("|");

            sb.append(d);

            if (mIsRecording) {
                sb.append("|1"); // this is the flag 
            }

            if (!canLogFile(sb.toString().getBytes().length)) {
                return false;
            }

            customLogFile.write(sb.toString());
            customLogFile.newLine();
```

So i am getting the data from console continuously and plotting the graph, but now after this i want to fetch the stored file data and wants to plot again in graph but segment wise like one interval of time to another interval (i.e like if flag is 1,then that data i want to fetch from the device and plot the graph, by taking pdMeanValue, aoMean value which will be there in side file as string format). (stored data structure is like [20|30|45|10|12|time will place here|flag])

Please help me to plot the graph by taking the value where the flag is 1.

Comment: Please post a few lines of such a file in a nice code block.

Comment: `After creating the file `. You should not create the file already. Remove that code. The new FileWriter() willl create the file.

Comment: Well if you do not want to reset the length to 0 there. What is the true parameter in new FileWriter() ?

Comment: Here as you can see `final String fileName = folderName + File.separator + firstName + "-" + patientId + "-" + procedureId + "-"
            + sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ".log"` this part should execute every time once app will open.And in my app one record option is there where by taking the flag only i am differentiating the record value and non record value. flag 1 is for record data and if noting is there means normal data.i have to create new file in my directory because of capturing the different different graph values.@greenapps